# Ignore/Skip part of string/extraction

Tags: xpath, domxpath

This is what I can work with:

```
<div class="rightCol3">
    <div style="padding:5px 25px 15px 35px;">
        <form action="/cart/add" method="post" name="poke">
            <div>
               <p class="love">
                  Wespon:&nbsp;Baazoka<br>
                  Size:&nbsp;Man-size&nbsp;tremendous
               </p>    
            </div>
        </form>
    <div>
<div>
```

I want to extract the weapon, using this solution:

```
/html/body//div[@class='rightCol3']/div/form/div/p[@class='love']//text()[count(preceding-sibling::br) < 1]
```

I manage to extract `Weapon: Baazoka`

Is it possible to skip "Weapon:" and only extract `Baazoka` ?

I am using Xpath 1.0/DOMXpath, no 2.0 please.

Answer (score 0):

are you allowed to use substring functions? if so, you can try

```
//div[@class='rightCol3']/div/form/div/p[@class='love']//substring-after(text()[count(preceding-sibling::br) < 1], ';')
```

Comment: I don't think substring functions are allowed with my code. But when I just tested it using Xpath Helper I get error [INVALID XPATH EXPRESSION] - is something wrong?